# Can't get CSS generated from a website to work, underwhat condition does the rule apply?

Tags: html, css

On another question I was recommended to [this site](http://daneden.me/animate/build/) which generates CSS but I can't get it to work. I am not skilled with CSS.

Here is the CSS code it generated plus I added some for testing purposes. The background is yellow, which I added to make sure the CSS file is loading correctly, but I can't get the text to shake. One thing I can't figure out is under what condition does the text shake, am I supposed to click something?

```
.animated{-webkit-animation-fill-mode:both;-moz-animation-fill-mode:both;-ms-animation-fill-mode:both;-o-animation-fill-mode:both;animation-fill-mode:both;-webkit-animation-duration:1s;-moz-animation-duration:1s;-ms-animation-duration:1s;-o-animation-duration:1s;animation-duration:1s;}.animated.hinge{-webkit-animation-duration:2s;-moz-animation-duration:2s;-ms-animation-duration:2s;-o-animation-duration:2s;animation-duration:2s;}@-webkit-keyframes shake {     0%, 100% {-webkit-transform: translateX(0);}    10%, 30%, 50%, 70%, 90% {-webkit-transform: translateX(-10px);}     20%, 40%, 60%, 80% {-webkit-transform: translateX(10px);} }

@-moz-keyframes shake {     0%, 100% {-moz-transform: translateX(0);}   10%, 30%, 50%, 70%, 90% {-moz-transform: translateX(-10px);}    20%, 40%, 60%, 80% {-moz-transform: translateX(10px);} }

@-o-keyframes shake {   0%, 100% {-o-transform: translateX(0);}     10%, 30%, 50%, 70%, 90% {-o-transform: translateX(-10px);}  20%, 40%, 60%, 80% {-o-transform: translateX(10px);} }

@keyframes shake {  0%, 100% {transform: translateX(0);}    10%, 30%, 50%, 70%, 90% {transform: translateX(-10px);}     20%, 40%, 60%, 80% {transform: translateX(10px);} }

.shake {    -webkit-animation-name: shake;  -moz-animation-name: shake;     -o-animation-name: shake;   animation-name: shake; }

body { background-color:yellow; }
```

[Here](https://github.com/daneden/animate.css/blob/master/README.md) are the author's notes. What does it mean "add the class animated to an element, along with any of the animation names"? This is how I interpreted it `<p class="animated"><p class="shake">This is a test</p></p>`

UPDATE: On [this page](http://daneden.me/animate/build/) it shows me an example of the CSS rule and the text does shake so it's not a browser compatibility issue. I tried as suggest my removing `-moz` like this but it still doesn't work.

```
.animated{-webkit-animation-duration:1s;-moz-animation-duration:1s;-o-animation-duration:1s;animation-duration:1s;-webkit-animation-fill-mode:both;-moz-animation-fill-mode:both;-o-animation-fill-mode:both;animation-fill-mode:both;}.animated.hinge{-webkit-animation-duration:2s;-moz-animation-duration:2s;-o-animation-duration:2s;animation-duration:2s;}@-webkit-keyframes flash {
    0%, 50%, 100% {opacity: 1;} 25%, 75% {opacity: 0;}
}

@-moz-keyframes flash {
    0%, 50%, 100% {opacity: 1;} 
    25%, 75% {opacity: 0;}
}

@-o-keyframes flash {
    0%, 50%, 100% {opacity: 1;} 
    25%, 75% {opacity: 0;}
}

@keyframes flash {
    0%, 50%, 100% {opacity: 1;} 
    25%, 75% {opacity: 0;}
}

.flash {
    -webkit-animation-name: flash;
    -moz-animation-name: flash;
    -o-animation-name: flash;
    animation-name: flash;
}
@-webkit-keyframes shake {
    0%, 100% {-webkit-transform: translateX(0);}
    10%, 30%, 50%, 70%, 90% {-webkit-transform: translateX(-10px);}
    20%, 40%, 60%, 80% {-webkit-transform: translateX(10px);}
}

@-moz-keyframes shake {
    0%, 100% {-moz-transform: translateX(0);}
    10%, 30%, 50%, 70%, 90% {-moz-transform: translateX(-10px);}
    20%, 40%, 60%, 80% {-moz-transform: translateX(10px);}
}

@-o-keyframes shake {
    0%, 100% {-o-transform: translateX(0);}
    10%, 30%, 50%, 70%, 90% {-o-transform: translateX(-10px);}
    20%, 40%, 60%, 80% {-o-transform: translateX(10px);}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add *both* classes to the same element, as in:

```
<p class="animated shake">Do the harlem shake!</p>
```

The `animated` class sets up general animation parameters, and the animation name class fills in the blanks and describes exactly what animation will take place.

**[See it in action](http://jsfiddle.net/kzXB4/)**.

Comment: Hate to be the barer of bad news but your example doesn't work in my FireFox or Internet Explorer. Has anyone else got it to work?

Comment: @Celeritas: I 'm not sure about why IE does not work (can't dig into compatibility tables right now), but for FF it's most likely because it's "too new". Remove the `-moz-` stuff from `.animated` and it will.

Comment: I've tried several browsers on different computers and none show your jsfiddle moving, does it move for you?

Comment: @Celeritas: Yes, latest Chrome and FF (after the tweak I mention above) both work.

Comment: I got it to work in FF! In jsfiddle I didn't know I had to click run. In IE 8 it hangs at the "Initializing the awesome!" screen. Sorry for not using the program right, though something fishy seems to be going on.